# UIPickerView : Keyboard not hiding

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have 3 UITexfield, the user can fill in the first two, but the last one is a category field and displays a UIPickerView when it's clicked.

What I've managed to do so far is :

- The user clicks on the catergory textfield -> the picker view appears
- Then the user clicks on another textfield -> the picker view disappears and the keyboard shows up

But know I would like to hide the keyboard when the user clicks agains on the category textfield and show the picker view.

This is what I have so far :

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if(textField == categoryTextField){
        [categoryTextField resignFirstResponder];
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"picker" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-236);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }else{
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"picker" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,236);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any thought why ?

Comment: you might want to look at resignFirstResponder/becomeFirstResponder methods. I had had a similar problem with the Keyboard and a pickerView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making it too difficult. Set the picker view as the input view of the textfield, and the OS will take care of the animations for you. As each field becomes first responder, the appropriate input view (default keyboard for the text ones, your picker for the third one) will be displayed. You don't need to do any animations yourself.

Comment: Ok, that works but I loose the animations, any idea how to keep them ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see where your problem comes from. I think that maybe your translation makes the pickerView move too far. You should try that :

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if(textField == categoryTextField){
        [categoryTextField resignFirstResponder];
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"picker" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        CGRect frame = pickerView.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 480 - 236; // assuming your on an iPhone and your picker appears from bottom
        pickerView.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }else{
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"picker" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        CGRect frame = pickerView.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 480; // assuming your on an iPhone and your picker disappears to bottom
        pickerView.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Hope that helps